# Jmeter hml request order get change when increase the number of users and due to that post reguler expression get failed

Tags: jmeter

1. I record and run the Jmeter script by keeping number of users = 1, in tread group.
2. Results tree output:
   [image: 1 user: result three]
3. I increased the number of users to 3 and result tree output order changed.
   [image: 2 Users: result Tree]
4. Therefore my some of regular expression exacter logics get failed and resultant responses failed. How can I avoid this situation.
   Is there way to manage result tree execution order.

[image: failures]

Comment: Provide the request and response snap for the failed request. Also, check if there is any error reported in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

If your regular expressions are under the requests and not at the same level as of HTTP requests then it should not be a problem.Every thread/vUser will run independently. But, in view results you will see request as and when executed by different threads and not in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) user manual chapter:

> **Variables are local to a thread**

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes Samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). JMeter threads are **absolutely** independent from each other and each thread has its own variables.

So the problem must be somewhere else, inspect the state of the variables using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and the response data for `/oauth` calls - it might simply not contain the necessary token value.

Also there is a suspicious call to `bundle.js`, my expectation is that you should not be executing it directly. The good practices is to configure [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to download embedded resources and use parallel pool to be closer to what real browsers do.

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults Embedded Resources]

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for more detailed explanation.